# Turn the object into a string

Tags: javascript

Transform the object into a string. Word order is given by the ASC sorting of the keys

```
const objetoInicial = {
  3: "aprendendo",
  4: "a",
  2: "estou",
  5: "manipular",
  6: "objetos",
  1: "Olá",
};
```

now I don't know how to print them.

Comment: You can loop through the object by using ```Object.values(object).forEach(//your code)```.

Comment: And where do you want to print it in console or inside of the ```html```?

Comment: `Object.values(objetoInicial).join(" ")`?